# tmap tm_add_legend alpha doesn't work for "fill"

Tags: r, gis, legend, r-sf, tmap

I'm trying to change the alpha value of my legend to match that of the polygon fill, however nothing seems to happen when I specify the alpha argument in `tm_add_legend`. Is there something blindingly obvious that i'm missing here?

```
library(tmap)
library(sf)

nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))

tm_shape(nc) + 
tm_polygons(col = "#326abf", border.col = "white", lwd = 2, alpha = 0.5) +
tm_add_legend(type = "fill", 
              alpha = 0.5,
              labels = "NC",
              col = "#326abf")
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure how tmap exactly works in this case. But I found a workaround. I created a dummy variable called `mycat`. Then, I used this variable for `col` in `tm_polygons()` and specify the color you are using in `palette`. In this way, you do not have to use `tm_add_legend()`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(sf)
library(tmap)

mutate(nc, mycat = "one") -> nc

tm_shape(nc) +
tm_polygons(col = "mycat", 
            palette = "#326abf",
            border.col = "white", lwd = 2, alpha = 0.5,
            title = "",
            labels = "NC")
```

[image]

Comment: That's a neat workaround, thanks! I'm still curious as to why alpha is not doing what I think it should be doing.

Comment: @geo_rkal I am not familiar with tmap. But it seems that `tm_add_legend()` is not linked to `tm_polygons()`. I have the impression that it is creating a custom/manual legend. If you check some examples of tmap, you do not see they use `tm_add_legend()`. In these examples, I saw that they actually assigned a variable to `col` as I did. In the way you wrote your code, you manually assigned one color to `col`. This is like the difference of whether you have `fill` in `aes()` or not in ggplot. Somehow tmap does not like your way.

Comment: @geo_rkal So my conclusion was to use `col` as if it were in `aes()` in ggplot. In this way, we can create the graphic above. I hope this explanation helps you to some extent.

Comment: Yes that makes sense. And you're right, `tm_add_legend` makes a manual legend but it doesn't seem to accept all the arguments in the way i thought it did. I'll stick to your method,